# Angular 11 mat input showing [object HTMLInputElement] when deleting content

Tags: angular, input, user-input, mat-input

I have a simple mat-input component that whenever I delete its content it shows [object HTMLInputElement] instead of empty field.
[Here is a working stackblitz of the problem.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ntfn1u?file=src/app/app.component.ts)
For project purposes I need to listen to every change of the input (not just when out of focus, but every input char).

**How to reproduce the error?**
Just put some input in the text field and then delete it, it will show [object HTMLInputElement] instead of an empty string.

I've added a console.log in the `handleInputChange` method that handles every change of text in the input field. By looking at the logs I saw that `event.target.value` has (correctly) the value of the inserted input, but then when deleting the input it has [object HTMLInputElement] and not an empty string as I would expect. Why is this happening?

Comment: May I know the significance of the following statement inside `handleInputChange` function, `const eventValue = event.value ? event.value : event` ? The ternary operator is resolving the value of variable `eventValue` to `event` which is why it is logging as `HTMLInputElement` when `event.value` is null or empty. Why not access the value directly via `event.value`? Check the updated code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-axiwxv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Easy. When `event.value === ''` then you're testing the following condition: `!event.value`. Keeping in mind that in javascript `!''` evaluates to `true`, then you are setting `value` to `event`, which is the `<input>` box

Comment: The best thing to do would be initialize the ts property: `value:string = ''`, and in your handler `this.value = event.value;`. Nothing less, nothing more. You're correct in using both `[value]` and `(change)`.